# Removing special characters from string in LUA

Tags: string, lua, null, special-characters

I'm trying to clean up a column of data containing postal codes before processing the values.  The data contains all kinds of crazy formatting or input like the following and is a CHAR datatype:

12345
12.345
1234-5678
12345 6789
123456789
12345-6789
.
[blank]

I would like to remove all of the special characters and have tried the following code, but my script fails after many iterations of the logic.  When I say it fails, let's say sOriginalZip = '.', but it gets past my empty string check and nil check as if it is not empty even after I have replaced all special characters, control characters and space characters.  So my output looks like this:
" 2 sZip5 = "

code:

```
nNull = nil
sZip5 = string.gsub(sOriginalZip,"%p","")
sZip5 = string.gsub(sZip5,"%c","")
sZip5 = string.gsub(sZip5,"%s","")
print("sZip5 = " .. sZip5)
if sZip5 ~= sBlank or tonumber(sZip5) ~= nNull then
    print(" 2 sZip5 = " .. sZip5)

else
    print("3 sZip5 = " .. sZip5)

end
```

Comment: To remove non-digits, try `string.gsub(sZip5,"%D","")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The issue I would have here is that there are also valid alphanumeric postal codes in the column, such as a Canadian "A1A 1A1".  Wouldn't this parameter remove the alpha characters from the postal code?

Comment: What is the full set of zipcode symbols?

Comment: To remove non-(digit-or-alpha), try `%W` instead of `%D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  there are different ways to go, following should work:

```
sZip5 = string.gsub(sOriginalZip, '.', function(d) return tonumber(d) and d or '' end)
```

It returns a number string, blank value or nil

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using a combination of yours and Egor's suggestions to get this:  sZip5 = string.gsub(sOriginalZip,"%W",function(d)return tonumber(d) and d or "" end)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!  I ended up using a combination of csarr and Egor's suggestions to get this:

```
sZip5 = string.gsub(sOriginalZip,"%W",function(d)return tonumber(d) and d or "" end)
```

Looks like it is evaluating correctly.  Thanks again!